# Stop execution of python script when parent Bash shell script is killed

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm working on a Bash shell script that runs several Python scripts like so:

```
cd ${SCRIPT_PATH}
python -u ${SCRIPT_NAME} ${SCRIPT_ARGS} >> $JOBLOG 2>&1
```

At one point, I killed the shell script (using `kill PID`), but the Python script continued running, even after the script terminated. I thought these would die as soon as the main script died. What am I misunderstanding about Bash scripting, and what can I do to get the functionality I'm looking for? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install a signal handler to *take care* of your child processes:

```
trap "echo killing childs; pkill -P $$"  EXIT
```

Comment: It looks like that will do it, although I think you need to trap more than just EXIT.

Comment: And an `exit` at the end of the trap commands, so the script itself will die too.

Comment: And this won't even work... since the trap arguments won't be executed until after the current line terminates, and it's the current line that I want to terminate.

Comment: No, signal handlers are called async. 

An no need to call exit at the and of the trap commands, because a exit handler is called ON TERMINATION of the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Children should be sent SIGHUP when the parent process dies - however:

a) The child process can ignore SIGHUP, or handle it a non-fatal manner.

b) The Child could disassociate itself from the parent process by fork() and becoming a process group leader.

You could just `exec` the python code, so that the shell is replaced with the python.

Comment: I see, thanks! I think (a) is the problem in my case (probably a bare "except" clause).